# How to set href urls in anchor tag at run time

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting url from api and trying to set it on anchor tag using forloop and javascript.
But unfortunately it is set only once. Please correct me where I am wrong.

```
{% for link in links %}
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">map link</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>
            <a id="anchor" href="">Click on map link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<script>
    var url = '{{route.summary.url}}';
    document.write(url);
    var element = document.getElementById('anchor');
    element.setAttribute("href", url);
</script>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

As u can see above I have printed the urls and they are like 2 urls which are there. Anchor tag is printed twice but href have only first  has url and that is the 2nd value of the url.
2nd  href is empty.

Comment: You are using the same ID "anchor" in each loop iteration, so the first pass is being overwritten by the second pass. You need to give your ID unique values. However, why not just put the url in the loop? `<a href="{{route.summary.url}}">`?

Comment: @timgavin was trying to use through java script. Yes id is the issue here.. 
Able to get values with above solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {% for link in links %}
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">map link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>
          <a class="map-link" href="#">Click on map link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    var url = '{{ link }}';
    console.log(url);
    var element = document.querySelector('.map-link');
    element.setAttribute('href', url);
  </script>
{% endfor %}
```

try using this , maybe the problem is that every id needs to be unique and changing it to class would myb help , also using different selector for inserting links

hope it will do

Comment: How would changing it to class help here?